# Use of subcaption in enumerate environment

Tags: lists, captions, enumerate, subcaption

This is a simple question. Say you were to place two (or more) related figures in an `enumerate` environment. Outside of an `enumerate` environment, which itself is a floating environment, you would probably work in a `figure` environment, using the `caption` and `subcaption` packages, and centering each figure with respect to the global text body. Now, in an `enumerate` environment, you include the figures directly, avoiding the additional use of a figure environment, and center the figures/subfigures together with their captions/subcaptions with respect to the local text body in the `enumerate` environment. In the case of a single figure, you could do this in a rather straightforward way (e.g., by using `\includegraphics{...}` and `\captionof{figure}{...}` nested within a centered environment). In the case of multiple figures (subfigures to be precise) I have found this fairly tricky I must say. How would I go about doing this? Many thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using the `subcaption` package and the `caption` package. Within the `enumerate` environment, you could use minipages for arranging subfigures, or even a table with any alignment you like. An easy example with a simple table and `\subcaptionbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item
\item Some figures:
  \captionsetup{type=figure}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{cc}
    \subcaptionbox{The first}{\includegraphics{fig1}}
    & \subcaptionbox{The second}{\includegraphics{fig2}} \\[1cm]
    \subcaptionbox{The third}{\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=1cm]{fig3}}
    & \subcaptionbox{The last}{\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{fig4}} \\
  \end{tabular}
\item Third item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{enumerate}
\item abc
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\centering\large A
\subcaption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1a}
\end{minipage}% 
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\centering\large B
\subcaption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:1b}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\item def
\end{enumerate}
\caption{What's this?}
\end{figure}
```

Instead of `\large A` and `\large B` put your `\includegraphics` commands.